# Restrict workflow to execute once in a lifetime for a library item

Tags: workflow

I am facing a problem in which I want the workflow to be executed only once when item in library is modified.

We have an option for "execute workflow when item is modified".
But I want to restrict the condition here, that it will be executed once in lifetime.

Suppose I again modified the item in library, then I don't want this workflow to be executed again.

Please someone can answer...
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an additional column in your library - say a yes/no column "IsWorkflowExecuted". Initially set to "No". 
Once your workflow is executed set that flag to "Yes". 
Your workflow first step should

1. Check IsWorkflowExecuted flag
2. Is No -Do your logic - Set to "Yes"